# Button to go back to the original PDF

Tags: pdf, documents, hyperlink

I am creating a PDF document, and I would to set a button which the reader could click and it would take them back to the last document.  For example, if I open a first document, and then click on a hyperlink, the other document is opened. In this second document, I want to set one button for going back to the first document.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Miguel, can you rewrite your question.  Its very hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: i open a first document, i set a hyperlink, then other document is opened. in this second document i want to set one button for going back to the first document :P

Comment: Is this PDF standalone, or is it viewed in a browser window?

Comment: this is a PDF standalone. the documents are in my PC, this is for one application in my job

Comment: "ALT+TAB" in windows.....

Comment: Ah, just noticed your clarification.  Please edit your first comment into the question.